# Changing chart type with multiple series highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have multiple series in highcharts similar to first [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) on highcharts. Now I am changing the chart type dynamically using following function

```
function ChangeChartType(chart, series, newType) {
    newType = newType.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        var srs = series[0];
        console.log(srs.options.data);
        try {
            srs.chart.addSeries({
                type: newType,
                stack: srs.stack,
                yaxis: srs.yaxis,
                name: srs.name,
                color: srs.color,
                data: srs.options.data
            },
            false);
            srs.remove(false);
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
    chart.redraw();
}
```

But both the series are not changing. Only one of the series is getting changed. What could be the error?

Answer (score 0):

Type of charts cannot be changed dynamically, only what you can do is destroy chart and create new. But this option should be available in 3.0 version.

Comment: thats what I am doing. I am destroying the series and then adding

Answer (score 0):

Does changing

```
        var srs = series[0];
```

to

```
        var srs = series[i];
```

help?

Comment: I got the result. Actually the code is correct. The error was somewhere else. It has to be series[0] because when the first series is removed, the second one becomes the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The error was somewhere else. Not in this function. The function is correct for changing the chart type.